# Use of the word would in a sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct "After I turned 17 I would go to Italy, but at that time I was only 16"?

Comment: **Yes, but**.  *Yes*, it's correct, *but* it's impossible to tell you if it's really right because you didn't tell us what you're trying to say.

Comment: i want to mean that i really went to Italy after i turned 17

Comment: I'm writing a memoir, and wanted to talk about the period when i was 16, and wanted to mention that later, after i turned 17, i went to Italy, Is this sentence would work fine to say that.?

Answer (score 1):

It is correct but

> After I turned 17 I would go to Italy

is a rather rare construction, meaning roughly the same as "I used to go to Italy", or I habitually went to Italy".

> After I turned 17 I would sing in nightclubs every weekend.

Perhaps you should just say "After I turned 17 I went to Italy...".

Comment: Actually, I think what the OP means is not "I used to go to Italy", but a kind of [future-in-the-past construction](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureinpast.html), meaning that at the time he was 16, his going to Italy was still in the future.

Comment: That is possible... "I had yet to go to Italy" perhaps. I think unless there is clarification from the OP I will leave this as is. There is no real need for a "future in the past" type construction in a simple bit of narrative.

Comment: I'm  writing a memoir, and wanted to talk about the period when i was 16, and wanted to mention that later, after i turned 17, i went to Italy, Is this sentence would work fine to say that.?

Comment: In which case use simple past After I turned 17 I went to Italy.

Comment: Is the the use of "would" in that case wrong?

Comment: "would" is a rather rare construction, meaning roughly the same as "I used to go to Italy", or "I habitually went to Italy".

Comment: @JamesK - I don't think that *would* has that meaning in this context.  Consider ["I enjoyed writing, and decided that someday I would go off to New York and become a famous playwright"](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pi_5iDA8xbAC&pg=PA63&dq=%22someday+I+would+go%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEhf2zyvnaAhWNVN8KHUpmDdEQ6AEINTAC) or ["Tomorrow I would start my investigation with a visit to her mother"](https://books.google.com/books?id=itAFVWA-0nIC&pg=PA36&dq=%22tomorrow+I+would%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi__Lidy_naAhVkg-AKHfrtD7k4ChDoAQhBMAQ) - it's the past tense of *will*, not a habitual action.

Comment: That is not how I would have understood the OPs original.  There could be ambiguity. I still think simple past is the proper tense to use for this narration